# is it possible to highlight the center line of viewport in VIM

Tags: vim

I'm working on a super long list, I keep pressing C-d to scroll the buffer, if the center line of the viewport can be highlight that would be nice to eye.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cursorline

```
:set  cursorline
```

Then you can press `M`, mnemonic "middle"